# Adding vertices and edges commit taking more time titan+cassandra

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop3

Adding Vertices and egdes taking more time. I am creating 4 Vertices and 3 Edges.

My code looks below

val conf = new BaseConfiguration ()

```
conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra")
conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1")
conf.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace","test")
conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading","true")

val graph: TitanGraph = TitanFactory.open (conf)



val start_time = System.currentTimeMillis()
val v0 = graph + "A"
for (nr <- List(B,C,D) {
    val v1 = graph +  nr
    v0 --- ("interference", 10) --> v1 
    }

    val end_time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    graph.tx.commit()
    println("Time taken to commit"+(end_time - start_time))
   }
```

This add 4 Vertices and 3 Edges.

**Time taken to commit 2785**  Time taken ~2 secs which is not very good.

Test Environment:

1. Start cassandra on windows machine
2. Enabled thrift -> nodetool.bat enablethrift
3. Connecting using the above configuraion

Any solution for this ? 
Batch commit is one option i could see . Even without commit also it is almost the same time.

Comment: I think there is some initialization that happens when you first start adding elements to the graph. Does performance improve after the first commit?

Comment: @Jason Plurad It does not seems to be imporving after many commits also.

Comment: Are you going through Gremlin Server?

Comment: I am trying from gremlin-scala . ** "com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.0.2-incubating.2", "com.thinkaurelius.titan" % "titan-core" % "1.0.0"** Storage-backend - cassandra